# how i write a code for delete from cursor in gtk entry

Tags: c, gtk, gtk2

how i write a code for delete from cursor in gtk entry

i write a code When I enter a text I delete it from button [image: image of entry button].

i try to delete only one character from entry cursor

i use g_signal_connect(): delete-from-cursor

but in callback (function) I do not know what to do

i use this code from source https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/signal.Entry.delete-from-cursor.html

the function void clicked_callback(GtkEntry* entry,GtkDeleteType type,gint count,gpointer user_data)
{

the code of application :

```
#include <gdk/gdk.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include<stdio.h>
void clicked_callback(GtkEntry* entry,GtkDeleteType type,gint count,gpointer user_data)
{
    g_print("pressed");
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    gtk_init(&argc,&argv);
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *entry;
    GtkWidget *grid;
    GtkWidget *button;
    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window),200,200);
    grid = gtk_grid_new();
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window),grid);
    entry = gtk_entry_new();
    gtk_widget_set_name(entry,"newname");
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window),entry);
    gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid), entry, 0, 0, 5, 1);
    button = gtk_button_new_with_label("I");
    gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid),button, 0, 1, 1, 1);
    g_signal_connect_swapped(button, "delete_from_cursor", G_CALLBACK(clicked_callback), entry);
    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which cursor do you mean, the mouse cursor or the entry cursor? Are you trying to delete only one character, or all the letters in the entry? Please [edit] your question to make it more clear; as it's currently written, it's hard to understand what you're asking.

Comment: the entry cursor Sylvester Kruin, i try to delete only one character from entry cursor

Comment: Do you want to delete the letter when the user presses a key, or when you call a function?

Comment: delete the letter when the user presses a key

Comment: The entry should already do that; you shouldn't have to program it yourself.

Comment: the entry should already, i Do not know how to program delete the letter when the user presses a key, help me pls.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241796/discussion-between-sylvester-kruin-and-karraz).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. The code here will be in Python, but I'll explain the principles, so hopefully it won't be to hard to translate to C.

What you need to do first is connect a function to the button's `clicked` signal. In Python, it looks like this:

```py
button = Gtk.Button.new_with_label("I")
button.connect("clicked", button_clicked_function)
```

In that function, you need to call the entry's `delete_from_cursor()` method, with `GtkDeleteType` of `CHARS` for the `type` argument, and a `-1` for the `count` argument. This `-1` tells it to delete 1 letter to the *left* of the cursor, instead of the right. Here is what this looks like in Python:

```py
def button_clicked_function(button):
    entry.do_delete_from_cursor(entry, Gtk.DeleteType.CHARS, -1)
```