# how to fix signal delete from cursor is invalid for instance of type GtkButton

Tags: c, gtk, gtk2

how to fix signal delete from cursor is invalid for instance of type GtkButton

i use the signal in gtk

```
g_signal_connect_swapped(G_OBJECT(button), "delete-from-cursor", G_CALLBACK(clicked_callback), entry);
```

the picture:

[image: invalid for instance]

Comment: Did [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71024315/16775594) not help you? Why are you still trying to connect a `GtkButton` to `delete-from-cursor`? `GtkButton` doesn't _have_ a `delete-from-cursor` signal; that's why you're getting this error.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what are you trying to do and the program flow you are expecting. You definitely need to read about GtkEntry and GtkEditable to understand them and how they works.

Comment: By the way, are you confident that you have been reading the `delete-from-cursor` signal documentation? More over, do you know what [Keybinding Signals](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-Bindings.html#GtkBindingSignal) are?